UBUNTU 24.04 freezes on data transfer after update
Both my lenovo p520 and my lenovo t460s have the same issue after updating to ubuntu 24.04 - when I insert an SD card to trasnfer data (mainly RAW files from DSLR) the PC will freeze and require restarting.
This happens almost instantly on the p520 and 80% of the time on t460s.
Has anyone experienced this? Ideally I'd like to avoid a clean install, though if needed - will have to go down that route.
Any info would be greatly appreciated :)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Within 5 minutes of the event, the terminal command sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes" will show system logs that cover the event. You can see the log entries just before the last crash with sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e.

Ah thank you : ) i shall try this next time it happens. Many thanks!!
